# Voltage Divider, increasing resistor value for solar tracker

Tags: arduino, resistance, voltage-divider

I am working on a solar tracking device based on arduino and I am using LDR's (Light Dependent Resistors) as voltage dividers.

The wiring is similar to this:

[image: 1]

The problem I am facing is that the sensors when in limited light work fine, but when exposed to sun, gives similar readings (not very different results) on all LDR's which I assume is because of very bright light source (sun) and light being reflected from other sources. The LDRs have also been divided using a cardboard structure like this:

[image: 2]

I am thinking of increasing the value of the carbon film resistors to achieve greater variations in voltage. Currently these are 10K. Will that solve the issue? Or I should try something else?

Comment: "The schematic is similar to this". No. That's not a schematic, it's a wiring diagram (and they are not "equivalent" if you're serious about electronics). IF you want to enhance your chances of getting useful answers try (a) to post the relevant schematic instead of a link (b) provide a "true schematic" not a wiring diagram.

Comment: Sorry, but to be frank, I don't have a wiring diagram to upload. The other thing is that, to display its connection with arduino, I feel the "wiring diagram" as you mentioned, is better. But, thanks for correcting me :)

Answer (score 2):

Edmund sells [these](http://www.scientificsonline.com/product/eclipse-shades):

[image: Eclipse shades]

If you take two of them apart and liberate the filters, you'll have four nice optical attenuators that you can place over the LDRs' windows for about a dollar each.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this kind of dynamic range problems is better solved by limiting the light. Add some filter, or maybe a king of net to cast shadow.

Answer (score 0):

you need potentiometer to increase tolerance value, i have simmiliar problem, but when i use potentiometer, the problem fix, this project help me so much http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Solar-Tracker/